# How to query Jackrabbit for a property value on all the file versions?

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I've got an application where I'm required to sync files from a remote server to JCR.

**Sync rules**

1. If a new file (file path) is found on the remote server, this file is added to JCR. Remote server also returns a `updateTimestamp` field which is stored as property to the content node as `updateTimestamp`.
2. If the file (file path) exists in JCR, but `updateTimestamp` received from the remote server is different to what we have in JCR then we add a new version of the same file in JCR with the new `updateTimestamp` set in the new file content node keeping previous version untouched.

Timestamp returned from the remote server is a `String` value in the format `dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss`

Rule 2 requires me to query all the version of the file with the property `updateTimestamp`. I've got the following query which returns all the files with the `updateTimestamp`. But is it possible to query all the version of this file with the property `updateTimestamp` ?

```
SELECT parent.*
FROM [nt:file] as parent
INNER JOIN [nt:base] as child ON ISCHILDNODE(child, parent)
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, [/files/id/documents])
AND parent.[jcr:path] like '%test1.wav%'
AND child.[cti:updateTimestamp] = '12/29/2016 11:53:54 PM'
```